# ASP.NET Core MySQL DB scaffold not working (could not find provider assembly)

Tags: mysql, asp.net, core, mvc

[This site](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html) shows how to reverse-engineer an existing database to an ASP.NET Core EF model.
What I found out is that the currently correct command should be (instead of "scaffold-dbcontext"):

> dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=mysqltestserver;userid=root;password=xx;database=yy;" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore

I am not sure about the Provider parameter, so I tried this one but it does not work:

> One or more errors occurred. (Unable to find provider assembly with name MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore. Ensure the specified name is correct and is referenced by the project.)

The new official MySQL EF Core packages have been existing only for a few days yet, so is this maybe a general problem in this version or could you tell me the correct provider?

Thank you

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, I moved to SQL Server Express temporarily.

Comment: Even I moved to MSSQL